# Different Types of Getter and Setter Methods

Tags: c#

I am implementing a getter and setter method for a property in a class. However, I would like to know the difference between the two getter and setter methods I have included below;

```
private string name { get; set; }
```

and

```
private string name; 

public string Name
{
    get { return name; } 
    set { name = value; }
}
```

Would I be able to use either?

Comment: Normally the lowercase `name` would be private and `Name` would be public. You can access both and they both will give the same value, the way you have it

Comment: @Jawad indeed. If the backing field is public and there is extra code in the property setter, setting the backing field directly will bypass that code.

Comment: Whatever changes you made now nullifies my response above. You cannot have a private member with a getter and setter... private fields are not accessible outside of the method which is why you use a public member with a getter and setter to update the private members

Comment: @Jawad - _You cannot have a private member with a getter and setter_ - well, you can, but why would you? Just use a field :)

Comment: @staurtd correct. You can set it with these I guess but it's pointless due to its protection level (private)

Comment: @stuartd - "but why would you?" - for exactly the same reasons to do it with a `public` property. The accessibility doesn't change why you would use a getter and a setter.

Comment: @Jawad - The purpose of public member with a getter and setter is not to update a private field. It can be used that way, but it's not the purpose.

Comment: @Enigmativity that's interesting, I've never (I think) used an auto-implemented private property (like in the edited question), do you have a use case to hand for one?

Comment: I find using private auto property useless, but i might be wrong

Comment: @stuartd - Don't get me wrong - I was talking about getters and setters in general and not auto properties specifically. Using a getters and setters on a private property makes sense specifically when you're not using auto properties.

Comment: @Enigmativity ok thanks, I was talking about the specific example of an auto-implemented property in the edited question, but I didn’t make that clear.

Answer (score 2):

They are basically the same. The first one is a syntactic sugar for the second one.

So instead of typing

```
private string name; 

public string Name
{
    get{ return name; } 
    set{ name = value; }
}
```

You just do

```
public string Name { get; set; }
```

EDIT: The backing field should be private

Comment: Well almost, as in the first case you retain access to the backing field `name`, which might be useful. For example, you use the first form if you have validation code in the setter.

Comment: @ja72 well yeah, depends of the situation. If you don't need to do some operations with the backing field, auto property works just fine

Comment: @Borka I am loading a name from a text file into the name and printing it out.

Comment: If you are using it just for storing and latter retrieving the value, then the auto property would be ok

Answer (score 1):

`{get; set;}` is called [Auto-Implemented Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties). It's internally does the same thing with your second code, but it makes you unable to edit the value without setter because it does not provide the name of internal field, unlike you can change the value of `name` without using the setter of `Name`.

Comment: _it makes you unable to edit the value without setter because it does not provide the name of internal field_ - it isn't clear what you mean here?